# How does the body survive Ebola?

Tags: virus, infection, ebola

Because Ebola takes over the immune system and uses it to replicate more and more of the virus, how does the body survive?

Is it a case of the virus being self-limiting and eventually just getting 'too big for its britches' so to speak? Or does the body somehow eventually start producing antibodies to fight it off?

Comment: From your text and the tag "retrovirus", I am wondering whether you are confusing ebola and HIV?

Comment: Nope I wasn't mixing up the two, I know that Ebola attacks the dendritic cells, monocytes, and macrophages. But I forgot about the T-cells and how it doesn't do much with them, HIV attacks those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the ebola virus infects [a lot of human cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC224575/), immune system cells it infects are mainly monocytes and macrophages. The cells in our body mainly responsible for adaptive immunity, [T cells](http://www.tcells.org/beginners/tcells/), are at least not completely infected:

> Our data indicate that 20–30% of CD4 and CD8 T cells died during the course of infection<sup>[1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0042682207000931)</sup>

That's a lot, but the ones that survive get activated and it's apparantly enough that [between 80 and 10% of the infected](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs103/en/) (depending on the strain) can survive the infection. [Little is known about the details of the immune reaction to ebola, but the immune system does get activated](http://www.pnas.org/content/112/15/4719.abstract). The immune system even remains on "high alert" for quite some time after infection and recovery.

And the antibodies do stick around, [at least for 10 years](http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/transmission/qas.html). Whether they confer immunity against all strains of ebola, we don't seem to know - ebola isn't very well-researched yet.

Comment: So, basically, if you can outlive the initial damage, you'll recover, no? That seems to be the gist of the treatment: keep them alive with fluids and, if necessary, blood. I remember a student nurse saved almost her entire family *at home* (not hospital) that way.

Comment: @anongoodnurse possibly? I think the morbid guideline I heard was that whoever isn't dead 7 days after onset of symptoms will probably make it. CDC says it's a mean of 7 days: http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/healthcare-us/preparing/clinicians.html with the dehydration being really horrible in the end